# What's the standard way to organize the contents of Java packages -- specifically the location of interfaces and abstract classes

Tags: java, oop, package

I suppose this could go for many OO languages.  I'm building my domain objects and am not sure where the best place is for the interfaces & abstract classes.

If I have a pets package with various implementations of the APet abstract class: should it live side-by-side with them or in the parent package?

How about interfaces?  It seems like they almost have to live above the implementations in the parent package, since there could potentially be other subpackages which implement it, while there seems to be a stronger correlation between one abstract class and a subpackage.

e.g.

```
com.foo
com.foo.IConsumer (interface)
com.foo.APet (abstract)
com.foo.pets.Dog extends APet implements IConsumer
```

OR

```
com.foo
com.foo.IConsumer (interface)
com.foo.pets.APet (abstract)
com.foo.pets.Dog extends APet implements IConsumer
```

or something else?

Comment: The other consideration is whether your interfaces are actually part of domain design, or if they're simply a pragmatic concession to the desire of certain popular application frameworks to create lots of JDK proxies.  Interfaces that serve no real design domain purpose and exist just so that the class can be JDK proxied by a container, I am inclined to simply leave in the same package right next to the implementation. (particularly since they tend to not be hard APIs and change right along with the class as the design evolves over sprints.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO interfaces and abstract classes are not so different in this respect. It is often better to keep the implementations in a separate package, especially if they are instantiated via a factory. This way these can be kept package private, so their implementation details are better hidden from clients.

So I would go with something like the first choice.

Answer (score 1):

Abstract classes are tricky, since both of your choices can feel right.  I usually decide it based on how much functionality is provided by the Abstract Class.  To extend your example:

```
com.foo.APet (Abstract Class)
com.foo.pets.ADog extends com.foo.APet (Also Abstract)
com.foo.pets.impl.Westie extends ADog (not abstract).
```

In this case APet is at the top because it provides the capabilities that are common to all pets.  ADog is definitely a pet, but contains those things common to all DOGS.  Classes in the impl package are produced by a factory or whatever, and specialize based on breed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of personal style, but I like (and I've seen others use) a structure where your interfaces and base or `final` classes are in the package proper, and the implementation classes are in an ".Impl" sub-package.  E.g., you'd have a `Pets` package with `Bird`, `Fish`, `Mammal` and `Reptile` interfaces, and possibly your base classes that implement those interfaces.  Then, you'd have a `Pets.Impl` package with specific classes for `Goldfish`, `Canary`, `Collie`, whatever.  That way, you can give people a `Bird` and not have to worry that they'll complain that it doesn't lay golden eggs, as that's an implementation detail specific to magic geese. :)